# Satellite looking angle calculation (non zero latitude for subsatellite point)

Tags: satellite

When calculating looking angles for geostationary satellites, it is assumed that because the satellites have an equitorial orbit, the latitude of the subsatellite point is 0. In reality, the latitude is not 0 (though really close to 0). If i just assume that the latitude is equal to 0, would that make my calculation inaccurate? If yes, how can we calculate angle of azimuth and elevation with non zero latitude for the subsatellite point.